# Derivative of composition $f(x,y,z)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Find $ \frac{du}{dx}$, if $u = f(x,y,z)$ and  $y = \phi(x)$, $z = \psi(x,y)$

Is that correct?

$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} =  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \left( \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)$

I'm not sure about the final part.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks good to me.  A little bit of notational nitpicking though would be to write $\frac{dy}{dx}$ versus $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$, since $y$ is a function of $x$ only.

Comment: Write $\frac{d\phi}{dx}$ instead of $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the chain rule.
$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\phi'+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}\phi')$

Comment: Of course.  And paper is made from trees.  And please replace $\phi'(x)$ by $\phi'$.